# Get request from browser works but using RestTemplate class I got 404 response for the same request

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I can easily get the expected JSON response if I send the following get request from my browser:

```
http://www.bookandwalk.hu/api/AdminTransactionList?password=XXX&begindate=2016-04-30&enddate=2016-10-12&corpusid=HUBW
```

I tried to use SPRING BOOT 1.4 to create a small demo app to see how rest calls work in Spring.
So I created a POJO representing my domain object and I requested the list of domain objects by the following method invocation:

```
String startDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(start.getTime());
String endDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(end.getTime());
UriComponents uri=UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("http").host("www.bookandwalk.hu").path("/api/AdminTransactionList").queryParam("password","xxx").queryParam("begindate",startDate).queryParam("enddate",endDate).queryParam("corpusid","HUBW").build().encode();

    LOG.log(Level.INFO,"{0} were called as a rest call",uri.toString());

    ResponseEntity<List<BandWTransaction>> transResponse =
            restTemplate.exchange(uri.toString(),
                        HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<BandWTransaction>>() {
                });

    List<BandWTransaction> transactions = transResponse.getBody();
```

I got the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
```

As I logged the uri.toString(), I copied it to my browser to double check the is there any typos in my uri but it was working without any failure.
Does Anybody have idea why the same string works from the browser but not from the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you should specify a user agent header in the request for this webapp. Use a HttpEntity object to set this header.

```
final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("User-Agent", "eltabo");

final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

ResponseEntity<List<BandWTransaction>> transResponse =
        restTemplate.exchange(uri.toString(),
                HttpMethod.GET, entity, 
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<BandWTransaction>>() {});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: you helped me a lot. Actually you drew my attention to the importance of httpheaders. I also set the accept header to MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.

Comment: Based on your question I have wrote a little example that may be useful if you need to add the same header to each request [Setting headers on Spring RestTemplate request](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/spring/5896/resttemplate/24622/setting-headers-on-spring-resttemplate-request#t=201610141133162153672)

Comment: thanks the additional support material for the restTemplate. By now at least I could get connected to the resource. Maybe it should be a new question but I still have one problem. The automatic message conversion through the Jackson HttpMessageConverter which is registered by Spring Boot results list of domain object with properties set to null.
My POJO includes exactly the same property names as in JSON and also the type of the properties are in line with the JSON data. Any idea what to check?

Comment: @Roland Please, post it as a new question adding the POJO you use, a piece of JSON data to map and any relevant information you can give (version of Jackson, ...)